# How does ssh run a command?

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm using Bash on both client and server. When running a command over SSH:

- `ssh <host> 'declare'` gives a list of shell variables.
- `ssh <host> 'mount'` gives a list of mountpoints.

However, `declare` is a Bash builtin, while `mount` is an external command. How does SSH know which to run if there is a shell builtin and an external command with the same name on the server?

Comment: ssh always run your shell, which is stored in `/etc/passwd`. If it's `/usr/sbin/nologin` you can't log in.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `ssh` runs the commands you provide in the remote user's shell (obtained from the `/etc/passwd`), as visible from the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L1673):

```
argv[0] = (char *) shell0;
argv[1] = "-c";
argv[2] = (char *) command;
argv[3] = NULL;
execve(shell, argv, env);
```

Therefore the respective commands that is executed for your example on the remote server are:

- `bash -c declare`
- `bash -c mount`

Both of them are passed to the `bash` and evaluated. Built-ins are evaluated inside, and the external commands are called as if you would do that from your local command line prompt.

Comment: If a shell is always started by ssh daemon, then the interesting thing is, when user calls ssh with a command, then that shell is not a login shell, even if user performed some kind of login. Any idea?

Comment: Yes. The shell running the command is 1) No a login shell 2) Not interactive one. You can force the interactivity by the `-t` switch, but it will still not load the rc files.

Comment: Note that `sshd` (the server) is doing this, not `ssh` (the client).

Comment: @ysdx They're working together. The client tells the server to execute the command through a shell, and the server does it.